# Get "Week of 2nd" from Date field in power BI

Tags: data-visualization, powerbi, dax

I have a date field in my DimDate table.

[image]

I want to get another column `WeekOf` that would show the week number based on Monday. 
For example I have date:

```
  Date         WeekOf
10/2/2017   Week of 2nd
10/9/2017   Week of 9th
10/16/2017  Week of 16th
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a new column with the following formula should give you what you want.

If you every want to change it to be the Week of a different day, change the `2` in the TargetDate variable to which ever day of the week you want.

```
WeekOf = 
    VAR TargetDate = DAY(DATEADD(Dates[Date], 2 - WEEKDAY(Dates[Date]), DAY))
    VAR TargetDateText = CONCATENATE(TargetDate, SWITCH(TargetDate, 1, "st", 21, "st", 31, "st", 2, "nd", 22, "nd", 3, "rd", 23, "rd", "th"))  

    RETURN
        CONCATENATE("Week of ", TargetDateText)
```

[image: Results]

Comment: That's awesome! Didn't even know about those tricks with variables.

Comment: @Oleg - I'm glad I could help. I haven't used variables much at all, but they seem super useful.