# Sorting by column gives an error. Power BI desktop

Tags: excel-formula, powerbi, powerpivot, dax

I have my DimDate table with column WeekOf.
[image]

In my visual weeks are not sorted. when I try to sort them it gives me an error.

How can I sort it properly?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knowing the formula behind the `WeekOf` column (from this SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46718183/7686897)), I would create a new column with the formula below and then set `WeekOf` to be sorted by `WeekOfSort`.

```
WeekOfSort = DAY(DATEADD(Dates[Date], 2 - WEEKDAY(Dates[Date]), DAY))
```